# Getting data attributes with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why do I have to put `data-*` in every `html child attribute` so i won't get `undefined` by clicking on `parent`? I.e

```
<li data-item="item-1">
  <img src="../img" alt="img" />
  <p>Some text</p>
</li>
```

By this example i will get `item-1` whenever i click near the borders of `<li>` but whenever i click either `img` or `text/paragraph` i get `undefined`. But when I set `data-item` on `<li>` childs i get normal `data` value. What?

PS. The way i get `data-*` is for example

```
handleClick(event){
  let data = event.target.dataset['item']
}
...
<li data-item="item-1" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>...</li>
```

What am I doing wrong, that I have to put into every `<li>` child `data-*` so I won't get undefined on whole `<li>` block `on<Event>`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

FYI, the problem has nothing to do with React. It's how DOM events in browsers work. Have a look [at this quirksmode.org article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) to learn more about how event propagation works.

[`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) will always refer to the element the event was triggered on. So if you click on the `<p>` element, `event.target` will refer to that element. Since `<p>` doesn't have a `data-*` attribute you get `undefined`.

To always get the element where the *handler is bound to* (i.e. the `<li>` element in your example), use [**`event.currentTarget`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead.

Comment: Hmm, indeed that solves the problem. Thanks for TL;DR and the article about `event.target`s